# How do I add a floater button with shortcut to a function key F7?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

We had old PDA machines with keypad and function keys and we have a web application that works on them made in classic ASP, jquery, and javascript. After the web application is opened, the user needs to press the F7 function to add a record for scanning a barcode.

Now the old PDA machines are dead and we are in process of purchasing android PDAs. The new machines don't have any keypad, it's just the touch screen. We tried adding a keyboard but there's not much space left on the screen to view the contents of the page and it is a bit tedious for the users.

Is there any way by which we can add a floater button on the page and by pressing it, it simulates function F7 press?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I did not test it, but should work... `document.dispatchEvent(new KeyboardEvent('keydown', {'code': 118}));`

Comment: Replacement the code for `{'key', 'f7'}` is also applicable.

Comment: I have tried below but it doesn't work, the function is not firing.
`function MyFunction() {
document.dispatchEvent(new KeyboardEvent('keydown',{'key':'f7'}));
}


var button = document.createElement("Button");
button.innerHTML = "F7";
button.style = "top:0;right:0;position:fixed;"
//button.onclick = function(){document.dispatchEvent(new KeyboardEvent('keydown',{'key':'f7'}));};
button.onclick = function(){myFunction();};
document.body.appendChild(button);`

Comment: Is there a reason you can't just perform the action rather than triggering the event that performs the action?

Answer (score 0):

The following script creates a `button` element which when clicked, initiates the `clickF7` function which *simulates* F7 key press.

```js
function clickF7() {
  document.dispatchEvent(new KeyboardEvent('keydown', { 'key': 'f7' }))
}

const button = document.createElement('button')
button.innerHTML = 'click f7'
document.body.appendChild(button)

button.onclick = clickF7

document.addEventListener('keydown', function (e) {
  if(e.key === 'f7') {
    console.log('clicked f7')
  }
})
```

EDIT: added listener to test `keydown` event
EDIT: tested on chrome

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this works like a charm but only after I have pressed at least 1 time f7 key. For the first time, it doesn't work.

Comment: Please be more specific od what's not working. I can see this snippet working on both mobile and desktop versions.

Comment: When the web page loads, it doesn't work the first time, the click doesn't do anything. But if I press f7 from the keyboard, then the button starts working. Something in the initialization.

Comment: If i click the button after the page loads on the firefox, edge and chrome, the event is fired. What browser do you test it on?

Comment: I am testing on Chrome